# ConcurrentHashMap synchronization issue

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, java-7, concurrenthashmap

I am using a `ConcurrentHashMap` with a `TreeSet` as value. This hash map is shared by multiple threads.

When a thread receives client request for a key, its checks if that key exists in hashmap, if yes it adds the new request as MyClass object in corresponding `TreeSet`. Otherwise creates a new `TreeSet` and inserts in `HashMap` with that key.

Code snippet:

```
public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, TreeSet<MyClass>> messageMap =
        new ConcurrentHashMap<String, TreeSet<MyClass>>();

TreeSet<MyClass> treeSM = new TreeSet<MyClass>();

if (messageMap.containsKey(key)) {
    treeSM = messageMap.get(key);
}

treeSM.add(sm);
messageMap.put(key, treeSM);
```

Here the map contains inconsistent values if two threads gets requests for same key simultaneously. Both threads gets result of `messageMap.containsKey(key)` as false and put the new build `TreeSet` object as key value. So eventually the `TreeSet` for that key has only one MyClass object instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck with Java 7, you want to do something like this instead to properly take advantage of `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
TreeSet<MyClass> treeSM = messageMap.get(key);     // 1
if (treeSM == null) {                              // 2
    TreeSet<MyClass> newTree = new TreeSet<>();    // 3
    treeSM = messageMap.putIfAbsent(key, newTree); // 4
    if (treeSM == null) {                          // 5
        treeSM = newTree;                          // 6
    }
}
synchronized (treeSM) {                            // 7
    treeSM.add(sm);                                // 8
}
```

Walking through the above lines of code:

1. Don't bother with `containsKey()` and just call `get()` instead. This will return `null` if the key isn't already in your map. *Most* of the time it is going to return non-`null`...
2. But if it *is* `null`...
3. Create a new `TreeSet` with the intention of putting that into the `Map`
4. Try to put the new `TreeSet` into the `Map` by calling `putIfAbsent()`. The semantics of `putIfAbsent()` are such that if the key is in the `Map`, it will just return the `TreeSet` that is already associated with they key. If the key isn't in the `Map`, it adds it to the `Map` and returns `null` instead. All of that occurs atomically.
5. If we get a `null` back from `putIfAbsent()`, that means that we successfully put our `newTree` into the `Map`, so we...
6. Copy the reference into `treeSM`
7. Because `treeSM` can be manipulated from multiple threads and is not a thread safe collection, we need to lock. In this case with a `synchronized` block.
8. We add our `MyClass` object to `treeSM`

The important take away from this is that any number of threads can execute the lines above and no matter how they are scheduled you will always have a valid `treeSM` reference when you get to line 7 and it will be the same `TreeSet` for all threads.

This becomes remarkably trivial with Java 8+:

```
TreeSet<MyClass> treeSM = messageMap.computeIfAbsent(key, x -> new TreeSet<>());

synchronized (treeSM) {
    treeSM.add(sm);
}
```

Comment: Thank Sean. Though I yet to run the load run for proper testing, it looks fine on initial tests. Thanks!

Comment: This fixes the check-then-act error of calling `containsKey` followed by `put`, however, this code is still broken, as it manipulates a `TreeSet` concurrently, which is not thread safe.

Comment: Note that you are mixing up `TreeSet` and `TreeMap` in your Java 8 example. Btw., Java 8 allows to perform the update under the key lock, i.e. `messageMap.compute(key, (x,set) -> { if(set==null) set=new TreeSet<>(); set.add(sm); return set; });`, but for this, you have to ensure that all updates have been completed before starting to read values…

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the other answer is *perfect* regarding "efficiency".

But just in case: the "super easy" solution would be to simply put some kind of locking around the corresponding code; either by having it in a *synchronized* method, or by using a lock object / synchronized block.

Comment: And if you were to do that, you would want to switch from using a `ConcurrentHashMap` to just a `HashMap` as there would no longer be a benefit to using the former.

Comment: Not necessarily. Having a synchronized put doesn't mean that other threads  can do safe reads on a ordinary hashmap at the same time?!

Comment: Actually, I see what you're saying now. I think it makes for a confusing synchronization policy, but I suppose it would work.